# XPATH - Grab td textual content if td above contains text beginning with certain letters

Tags: xpath

```
<tr>
                <td class="">Principal</td>
                <td class="">Mr Steve Brown</td>
            </tr>
```

I am trying to output "Mr Steve Brown", I only want this if the td class above contains certain text, in this case I would be looking for "Princ" as this would cover the plural version of principal too. I am trying variations of this:

```
//td[contains(preceding-sibling::td, 'princ')]/td
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below XPath to get required output:

```
//td[starts-with(., "Princ")]/following-sibling::td
```

Note that both `td` are *siblings* while `//td/td` means that you are looking for `td` which is *child* of another `td`